# What should the redlines be?

Tags: discussion

It was said in the chat that there are no [redlines](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6974183#6974183), so I would like to ask what should the redlines be?

Answer (score 2):

Extremely good question. I think in Islam.SE we should get our limits also from Islam.

- Insulting the others, Muslims or non-Muslims:

> وَلاَ تَسُبُّواْ الَّذِينَ يَدْعُونَ مِن دُونِ اللّهِ فَيَسُبُّواْ اللّهَ عَدْوًا بِغَيْرِ عِلْمٍ

- Sectarianism and breaking the community:

> وَاعْتَصِمُوا بِحَبْلِ اللَّهِ جَمِيعاً وَلا تَفَرَّقُوا

- Calling a group of Muslims (who believe in Allah and prophet Muhammad - PBUH) Kafir

> وَلاَ تَقُولُواْ لِمَنْ أَلْقَى إِلَيْكُمُ السَّلاَمَ لَسْتَ مُؤْمِناً

If something is beyond the redlines, it should be closed/deleted. But if some post is not violating the redlines it should be fully tolerated.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [etiquette](/questions/tagged/etiquette), [faq-content](/questions/tagged/faq-content), [sectarianism](/questions/tagged/sectarianism), [islam](/questions/tagged/islam), and in general [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) (this is a much broader set of meta posts, but you'll find everything there).

Aside from that, [the faq](https://islam.stackexchange.com/faq) has a lot of "red lines" which are good to know.