# Close or Comment?

Tags: discussion

What is the best strategy when we see some question does not fully match the website policies, but can be modified to match? I mean the questions that do not break the [redlines](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/587/what-should-the-redlines-be)

- Closing it immediately by a single moderator click
- Let it to see if the community makes 5 close votes over the post
- Downvoting the question and making a comment why it does not fit the website policies
- Editing the question and letting it to be peer-reviewed by the asker/community

Answer (score 2):

Close and comment. Closing is a *temporary* state, unlike how closing works on forums. Many closed questions can be edited to fit the rules, and then reopened. If you feel a post is salvageable, comment somewhat like:

> (Welcome to Islam Stack Exchange!) Unfortunately, your question is/has (list issues), and I am (closing/voting to close) it as (OT/NARQ/NC/Too localized). If you can edit it so that (something), we'd be happy to reopen it.